# How to show Recycler View on Popup Dialog?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have made a List using `RecyclerView` and custom the list using `CardView`.
Here's the code:

**activity_caddy.xml** (the `RecyclerView`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.user.ayogolf.CaddyActivity">



      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="551dp"
            android:id="@+id/rvcaddy"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**`activity_custom_list_caddy.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgcaddy"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/no_photo" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtcaddy_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="Caddy Name"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtgender"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="Gender"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then I have an adapter for the `RecyclerView` like this:

**`CaddyAdapter.java`**

```
package com.example.user.ayogolf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.user.ayogolf.Retrofit.Caddy;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by arifina on 7/26/2017.
 */

public class CaddyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CaddyAdapter.MyHolder>{

    ArrayList<Caddy> data;
    RecyclerView r;
    Context c;
    int resource;

    public CaddyAdapter(ArrayList<Caddy> data, Context c, int resource) {
        this.data = data;
        //this.r = r;
        this.c = c;
        this.resource=resource;
    }

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //array position
            int posisi = r.getChildLayoutPosition(v);
            Intent intent = new Intent(c,CoFormActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pic",data.get(posisi).getCaddy_pic());
            intent.putExtra("name",data.get(posisi).getCaddy_name());
            intent.putExtra("gender",data.get(posisi).getGender());
            c.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    @Override
    public CaddyAdapter.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_list_caddy,parent,false);

        v.setOnClickListener(listener);
        return new MyHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CaddyAdapter.MyHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textnama.setText(data.get(position).getCaddy_name());
        holder.textgender.setText(data.get(position).getGender());
        Glide.with(c)
                .load("http://192.168.2.32/ayogolf/uploads/caddy/"+data.get(position).getCaddy_pic())
                .into(holder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView textnama;
        TextView textgender;
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgcaddy);
            textnama = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcaddy_name);
            textgender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtgender);
        }
    }
}
```

and i want to show the popup on my CoForm by clicking buttoncaddy but when i click the button, there's only show a white blank popup..

**here's the code:**

```
    package com.example.user.ayogolf;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.user.ayogolf.Retrofit.ApiServices;
import com.example.user.ayogolf.Retrofit.Caddy;
import com.example.user.ayogolf.Retrofit.InitRetrofit;
import com.example.user.ayogolf.Retrofit.ResponseServer;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class CoFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.txtcourse)
    TextView txtcourse;
    @InjectView(R.id.spinnerhour)
    Spinner spinnerhour;
    @InjectView(R.id.txthour)
    TextView txthour;
    @InjectView(R.id.spinnerplayer)
    Spinner spinnerplayer;
    @InjectView(R.id.txtplayer)
    TextView txtplayer;
    @InjectView(R.id.checkBox3)
    CheckBox checkBox3;
    @InjectView(R.id.button20)
    Button button20;
    @InjectView(R.id.txtprice)
    TextView txtprice;
    @InjectView(R.id.txtn)
    TextView txtn;
    @InjectView(R.id.buttoncaddy)
    Button buttoncaddy;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    private TextView tvDateResult;
    private Button btDatePicker;

    String[] hour = {"--Hour--", "06:00", "06:30", "07:00", "07:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30"};
    String[] player = {"--Player--", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_co_form);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        //buat variabel untuk menangkap string yang dipindahkan dari activity lain
        String course = in.getStringExtra("course");
        String price = in.getStringExtra("price");
        txtcourse.setText(course);
        txtprice.setText(price);
        ArrayAdapter adapterhour = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hour);
        spinnerhour.setAdapter(adapterhour);

        spinnerhour.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                txthour.setText(hour[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter adapterplayer = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, player);
        spinnerplayer.setAdapter(adapterplayer);

        spinnerplayer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                txtplayer.setText(player[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

        tvDateResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dateresult);
        btDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_datepicker);
        btDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDateDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showDateDialog() {

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                /**
                 * Method ini dipanggil saat kita selesai memilih tanggal di DatePicker
                 */

                /**
                 * Set Calendar untuk menampung tanggal yang dipilih
                 */
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                /**
                 * Update TextView dengan tanggal yang kita pilih
                 */
                tvDateResult.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        /**
         * Tampilkan DatePicker dialog
         */
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.checkBox3, R.id.button20, R.id.buttoncaddy})
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttoncaddy:
                //create dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CoFormActivity.this);
                //set layout custom
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_caddy);
                final RecyclerView rvcaddy = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rvcaddy);

                ArrayList<Caddy> data = new ArrayList<>();
                CaddyAdapter adapter = new CaddyAdapter(data, this, R.layout.activity_caddy);
                rvcaddy.setAdapter(adapter);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                rvcaddy.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                dialog.show();

                break;
            case R.id.checkBox3:
                //create dialog
                //final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CoFormActivity.this);
                //set layout custom
                //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_caddy);

                //dialog.show();

                break;
            case R.id.button20:
                String hour = txthour.getText().toString();
                String player = txtplayer.getText().toString();
                String price = txtprice.getText().toString();
                if (hour.equalsIgnoreCase("--Hour--")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Choose Time!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (player.equalsIgnoreCase("--Player--")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Choose Number of Player!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    int player2;
                    player2 = Integer.parseInt(player);
                    int price2 = Integer.parseInt(price);
                    int total = price2 * player2;
                    String total2 = String.valueOf(total).toString();
                    String price3 = String.valueOf(price2).toString();

                    //pindah activity dan mengangkut data
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CoFormActivity.this, ReceiptActivity.class);
                    //untuk mengangkut data dari class ke class lain
                    intent.putExtra("course", txtcourse.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("date", tvDateResult.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("time", txthour.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("player", txtplayer.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("price", price3);
                    intent.putExtra("total", total2);
                    if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
                        intent.putExtra("caddy", "YES");
                    } else {
                        intent.putExtra("caddy", "NO");
                    }
                    //eksekusi intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

what should I do to show my popup with lists of data? what thing should I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did add any item to the list while setting the recycled view. You just created like this `ArrayList<Caddy> data = new ArrayList<>();` and you added into the list, so size will be always "0".

```
   case R.id.buttoncaddy:
        //create dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CoFormActivity.this);
        //set layout custom
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_caddy);
        final RecyclerView rvcaddy = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rvcaddy);

        ArrayList<Caddy> data = new ArrayList<>();
        CaddyAdapter adapter = new CaddyAdapter(data, this, R.layout.activity_caddy);
         // Add some item here to show the list.
        rvcaddy.setAdapter(adapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rvcaddy.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        dialog.show();

        break;
```